# CFLogin fails Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I am trying to deploy a project on IoT bluemix. I have created 3 devices, but the cf login command fails. It says authentication failed. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: could you please provide more details of your problem? At a minimum please add the command you tried with the error and the version of cf you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The three most likely reasons your `cf login` would fail (besides invalid username/password) is because:

1. You are connected to the wrong API endpoint. Use `cf api` to verify that you are connected to the API endpoint you would like to authenticate against.
2. Your organization requires the `--sso` flag. This uses a one-time password to login.
3. Your API endpoint is behind a firewall, so you need to VPN into the right network.